# How can I see/monitor backlog queue (pending TCP connections in the queue) on windows server?

Tags: networking, tcp, windows-server, tcpserver

How can I see/monitor `TCP` connections in `backlog` queue on `Windows Server`?
Any tools or PS scripts or anything else to monitor the queue in real time would be appreciated.

I searched around, didn't find anything useful.